# Stripe checkout pull value from html

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am going to be placing a value in a custom data type. I am using stripe checkout and am trying to have it so a span text content, so that I can turn that value/text into a variable.

HTML:

```
                        <!--Totals-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
                          <p class="lead">Amount Due <?php echo '$date'; ?> + <?php echo '$paymentdatesetting'?></p>
                          <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <th style="width:50%">Subtotal:</th>
                                  <td id='subtotal'>$subtotal</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Tax ($tax-country)</th>
                                  <td><?php echo '$total-tax'; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Shipping:</th>
                                  <td><?php echo '$shipping'; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Total:</th>
                                  <td>$<span id='total'>100</span></td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/Totals-->
```

Ignore the php code that is mostly sudo code that is to remind me of things.

JS and stripe checkout code:

```
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                            var totalvalue = document.getElementById("#total").textContent="newtext";
                          </script>


                          <form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
                            <script
                              src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
                              class="stripe-button"
                              data-key="pk_test_HwlcQ0e8VwlFkQJu46vynuPT"
                              data-amount= totalvalue
                              data-name="SeaitManageit"
                              data-description="Inovice"
                              data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                              data-locale="auto"
                              data-currency= invoicecurency>
                            </script>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Am I right in believing you're trying to pass custom data/variables from Javascript to your stripe server side code?

Comment: Not sure, but what I am trying to do is I want the 100 from the span with id='total' using JS     var totalvalue = document.getElementById("#total").textContent    than use that variable down at the data-amount attribute in the stripe code. The stripe code is almost all taken from their site and it all works but the amount.